# Concatenate MongoDB Queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Users share posts in my website and every post has a city and category and vote option.I have a menu on the top help users to filter posts on city, category, top voted and newest.  What Im trying to do is:

- If a user change the city then I will return all posts on that city.
- If this user also change the category. well I have to return the posts with that category but also the city.
- If the user chose newest well I have to return the newest posts in that category, in that city.
- And I have a special option in city list. Which should return posts in all cities. And in category list as well.

I'm using Meteor & end up doing this spaghetti:

```
if ( Session.get('topPosts') ){
    if(Session.get("selectedCity") && Session.get("selectedCategory")){
        if (Session.get("selectedCity") === Cities[0] && Session.get("selectedCategory") === Categories[0]){
            return Posts.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}});
        }
        else if (Session.get("selectedCity") === Cities[0]){
            return Posts.find({ category: Session.get("selectedCategory") }, {sort: {score: -1}});
        }
        else if (Session.get("selectedCategory") === Categories[0]){
            return Posts.find({ city: Session.get("selectedCity") }, {sort: {score: -1}});
        }
        return Posts.find({ city: Session.get("selectedCity"), category: Session.get("selectedCategory") }, {sort: {score: -1}});
    }
    ..
```

I'm new to mongodb. I don't know if I can achieve this with a simple query or combining between multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a different query for each search possibility, you can assemble a single set of search and sort parameters and apply them at the end.

```
var selector = {};
var sort = {};
if (Session.get('selectedCity') selector.city = Session.get('selectedCity');
if (Session.get('selectedCategory') selector.category = Session.get('selectedCategory');
if (Session.get('topPosts') sort = {sort: {score: -1}};
return Posts.find(selector, sort);
```

I'll let you work out how to do your special city option.